# Where is the MachineKeys folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, security, .net-framework, c#

I know where the `MachineKeys` folder in `XP`. Anybody can tell me where it is in `Windows 7`?

Comment: what framework version are you referring to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In clean installation of Windows you can find it under C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

In newer versions of Windows, try: %SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

Answer (score 2):

> C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

And make sure the folders are not invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the same location.. its protected but, I got there with some effort:
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\

Comment: C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys is probably the 'correct' location, while the documents and settings path is probably for application compatibility.

Comment: Actually `C:\Users\All Users` is a junction to `C:\ProgramData` too

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to the machine keys in the machine.config file, in that case it depends on what version of the .NET framework you want, it should be in the default location, for example .NET 4.0:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
```